# Xubuntu/xfce Some .txt files won't open text editor

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, gedit, filemanager

I have strange behaviour on my Xubuntu installation when opening text files from the File manager by double click.

Many text files with the extension .txt from a SMB share do not react on a double click. Same if I copy them to a local drive. When I create a new file in the file manager and name it "text.txt" it will open upon double click.

I found many posts about defining the default editor in /use/share/application/defaults.list or .local/share/application/with some override settings and references to the MIME Editor. I tried them and all have text/plain set to gedit which is what I need.

I can not understand why it just does not work with all text files. I can not rule out that the affected files have been created in Windows.

Any ideas what is causing that and how I can fix that? Currently workaround is to open every file with right mouse click and select gedit manually from 'Open with Other Application...'.

In case it matters, I am using Xubunut/xfce 16.04. I have the same with Thunar and Nemo file managers

Added info: 
I copied a non working text file to my local drive, opened it with "Open with Other Application.." and edited it a bit with gedit and saved it again. I wanted to make sure the format is a valid gedit writable format. I got no errors. Still the file does not open by double click.

Comment: have you tried right click ---> open with other  then select gedit and check make default?

Comment: yes, first thing I did. My issue is that it works only for *some* files, for other not.

Comment: When you make it default of some file, then all files of the same *type* will have the new default as well. Other types won't. Repeat as much you need to make it default for all file types you want.

Comment: @MichaelBay Sorry I was unclear. Example: I made ".txt" default to open with gedit. As a result I have some .txt text files that open with gedit and at the same time I have other .txt text files that do nothing. That means I double click on them and nothing happens. I need to right click them, select "open with another application" and select gedit to open them. Only then they display fine and show no artifacts. My issue is that I do not understand why those 2 files are not handled the same way. I can not tell any difference between those (except that of course they contain different texts).

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with Mint Mate 18.1, text files created on this computer open normally with a double click. Text files copied from another computer when double clicked do nothing. Only way I've found to make it work right is to do a save as to the desktop, then overwrite the old file with the new one.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/740667)

Comment: @Henning Kockerbeck I can not see why it would not qualify as an answer. It gives a workaround to the same issue - even when on another distro.

Comment: @Scott Good idea, but unfortunately it does not work in my case. I opened the file without double click in gedit and saved it from there with the same name. Gave me the same result.

Comment: @Scott Correction, your suggestion does work as work around, indeed. However, it requires that I save the file under a temorary name, delete the old file and change the temp name to the original one. Checked with gedit. So I give that an up vote as a valid workaround, but I hope there is a better way. I have no idea why the above procedure works and save as with the same name and saying 'OK' to replace file does not.